# The ways I've tried to reset my game lead to either not executing the main, or a new black jFrame freezing

Tags: java, swing

I have a blackjack game with a guy that has a reset button in the ActionListener. However, when I use it, much of the program's functionality isn't there. The reset is invoked by:

```
    public class BlackjackGameTable extends JFrame{

  JButton stayButton = new JButton("STAY");
  JButton hitButton = new JButton("HIT");
  JButton resetButton = new JButton("Reset");
  JLabel background;
  Hand playerhand = new Hand();
  Hand dealerhand = new Hand();
  JLabel score;
  JLabel text;




  class DecisionListener implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a){
      if(a.getSource() == hitButton){

        CardGame2.hit(playerhand, dealerhand);        
        playerAddCardToTable(new CardRender2(playerhand.cardlist.get(playerhand.getSize()-1)));

       score.setText("Your score: " + playerhand.getScore());
       System.out.println("YOU CHOSE HIT! Your Score: " + playerhand.getScore());

      }    
      else if(a.getSource() == stayButton){
        System.out.println("YOU CHOSE STAY!");
      }
      else if (a.getSource() == resetButton){

           //I've tried this below
           dispose();
           new BlackjackGameTable()
           //this almost works but the main doesn't execute

           //I've also tried:
           dispose();
           main(null);
           //I get a black jframe

          //and lastly 
          dispose();
          new BlackjackGameTable().main(null);

      }

    }
  }



  public BlackjackGameTable(){

    this.setTitle("Blackjack");
    background = new TableComponent();
    background.setLayout(null);
    this.add(background,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setSize(1300,867);

    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    score = new JLabel("Your score: " + playerhand.getScore() );
    text = new JLabel("WELCOME TO BLACKJACK!");
    ActionListener pressChoice = new DecisionListener();
    hitButton.addActionListener(pressChoice);
    stayButton.addActionListener(pressChoice);
    resetButton.addActionListener(pressChoice);
    buttonPanel.setSize(300,150);
    buttonPanel.add(text, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    buttonPanel.add(hitButton,BorderLayout.WEST);
    buttonPanel.add(stayButton,BorderLayout.EAST);
    buttonPanel.add(score, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    buttonPanel.add(resetButton, BorderLayout.EAST);

    buttonPanel.setVisible(true);
    this.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    CardGame2.dealIn(playerhand);
    CardGame2.dealInDealer(dealerhand);
    CardRender2 playerFirstCard = new CardRender2(playerhand.cardlist.get(0));
    CardRender2 playerSecondCard = new CardRender2(playerhand.cardlist.get(1));
    background.add(playerFirstCard);
    playerFirstCard.setBounds(0,110, playerFirstCard.image.getWidth(), playerFirstCard.image.getHeight());
    background.add(playerSecondCard);
    playerSecondCard.setBounds(120, 110, playerSecondCard.image.getWidth(), playerSecondCard.image.getHeight());

    CardRender2 dealerFirstCard = new CardRender2();
    CardRender2 dealerSecondCard = new CardRender2(dealerhand.cardlist.get(1));
    background.add(dealerFirstCard);
    dealerFirstCard.setBounds(0, 550, dealerFirstCard.image.getWidth(), dealerFirstCard.image.getHeight());
    background.add(dealerSecondCard);
    dealerSecondCard.setBounds(120,550,dealerSecondCard.image.getWidth(), dealerSecondCard.image.getHeight());

    score.setText("Your score: " + playerhand.getScore());
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

  } 

  public void playerAddCardToTable(CardRender2 c){

    background.add(c);
    c.setBounds((playerhand.getSize() - 1) * c.image.getWidth(), 110, c.image.getWidth(), c.image.getHeight());
    revalidate();
  }

  public void dealerAddCardToTable(CardRender2 d){
    background.add(d);
    d.setBounds((dealerhand.getSize() -1) * d.image.getWidth(), 550, d.image.getWidth(), d.image.getHeight());
    revalidate();
  }

  public void dealerReveal(){
    CardRender2 dealerOGCard = new CardRender2(dealerhand.cardlist.get(0));
    background.add(dealerOGCard);
    dealerOGCard.setBounds(0, 500, dealerOGCard.image.getWidth(), dealerOGCard.image.getHeight());
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){

    System.out.println("Welcome to Blackjack!\n");
    BlackjackGameTable g = new BlackjackGameTable();
    System.out.println("Dealer hand: " + g.dealerhand.cardlist + " " + g.dealerhand.getScore());
    System.out.println("Your hand: " + g.playerhand.cardlist + " " + g.playerhand.getScore());

    boolean playerStillIn = true;

    while((playerStillIn) && (!CardGame2.isBusted(g.playerhand))){
      if(g.playerhand.getScore() != 21){
        g.text.setText("Hit or stay?");

        if(g.hitButton.getModel().isPressed()){


          g.score.setText("Your score: " + g.playerhand.getScore());
          System.out.println("YOUR HAND: " + g.playerhand.cardlist);
          System.out.println("YOUR SCORE: " + g.playerhand.getScore());
        }
        else if (g.stayButton.getModel().isPressed()){
          playerStillIn = false;

        }
      }
      else{
        System.out.println("BLACKJACK 21!!! YOU WIN BIGLY");
        g.text.setText("BLACKJACK 21!!! YOU WIN BIGLY");
        g.dealerReveal();
        break;
      }
    }

    if (CardGame2.isBusted(g.playerhand)){
      System.out.println("BUSTED! YOU LOSE!!");
      g.text.setText("BUSTED! YOU LOSE!!");
      g.dealerReveal();
    }
    else{

      while(((g.dealerhand.getScore() < 17) && (CardGame2.noBusted(g.playerhand,g.dealerhand))) &&(g.playerhand.getScore() != 21)) {
        CardGame2.hit(g.dealerhand,g.playerhand);
        g.dealerAddCardToTable(new CardRender2(g.dealerhand.cardlist.get(g.dealerhand.getSize()-1)));
      }




      if ((g.playerhand.getScore() == g.dealerhand.getScore())) {
        System.out.println("DEALER HAND: " + g.dealerhand.getHand() + " and SCORE: " + g.dealerhand.getScore());
        System.out.println("YOUR HAND: " + g.playerhand.getHand() + " and SCORE: " + g.playerhand.getScore());
        System.out.println("PUSH");
        g.text.setText("PUSH");
        g.dealerReveal();
      }

      else if((CardGame2.isBusted(g.dealerhand)) && (g.playerhand.getScore() != 21)){
        System.out.println("DEALER HAND: " + g.dealerhand.getHand() + " and SCORE: " + g.dealerhand.getScore());
        System.out.println("YOUR HAND: " + g.playerhand.getHand() + " and SCORE: " + g.playerhand.getScore() );
        System.out.println("YOU WIN");
        g.text.setText("YOU WIN");
        g.dealerReveal();
      }



      else if ((g.playerhand.getScore() < g.dealerhand.getScore())) {
        System.out.println("DEALER HAND: " + g.dealerhand.getHand() + " and SCORE: " + g.dealerhand.getScore());
        System.out.println("YOUR HAND: " + g.playerhand.getHand() + " and SCORE: " + g.playerhand.getScore());
        System.out.println("YOU LOSE");
        g.text.setText("YOU LOSE");
        g.dealerReveal();
      }

      else if ((g.playerhand.getScore() > g.dealerhand.getScore()) && g.playerhand.getScore() != 21)  {
        System.out.println("DEALER HAND: " + g.dealerhand.getHand() + " and SCORE: " + g.dealerhand.getScore());
        System.out.println("YOUR HAND: " + g.playerhand.getHand() + " and SCORE: " + g.playerhand.getScore());
        System.out.println("YOU WIN");
        g.text.setText("YOU WIN");
        g.dealerReveal();
      }



    }
  }
}
```

how might I go about getting this reset?

Comment: Your `while-loop` in the `main` method is a bad, bad idea. When first run, it's updating the UI from outside the context of the EDT, if you try and run it again (from within the EDT), it will block it and prevent the EDT from been able to update the UI. You seem to be working in a "procedural" mindset, as if you're converting a console based program to a GUI, this is the wrong approach. GUIs are event driven, something happens, you react to it. You're going to need to go back and re-thing/re-design your app to fit within this model to solve your problem

Comment: I would start by having a look at [The Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) for a brief explantion

Comment: I will, just as I ultimately decided to use components for my images as people suggested. But seeing as I'm so close to getting this game to at least play, is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Remove the while-loop, rely on the event system to manage the state

Comment: are you saying that a LOT more code needs to go into actionPerformed?? I always thought that was supposed to be a short method. I spent forever getting this game to work in the console, and the while loop and boolean is in part why.

Comment: I'm saying that the `while-loop` is your issue and you should be making use of the event based system. You can use your existing `ActionListener`, but I'd break down the code into sections of methods which can perform specific tasks based on the current state. You can also use anonymous or inner listeners to provide focused functionality

Comment: You can't translate console code structure and program flow directly into an event-driven GUI programming paradigm. Yes, you need to get rid of the while loop and re-think program flow.

Comment: good idea; I've done it and it works very well with calling main(null). Big league thanks!